# Spring Boot Configuration Processor does not work in a library / gradle subproject

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin

Software:

- Gradle **5.5.1**
- Kotlin **1.3.50**
- Spring Boot **2.2.0.M5**

---

I'm trying to use spring-configuration processor in a library. I have following configuration.
In parent `build.gradle.kts`:

```
subprojects {
  dependencies {
    implementation(platform(SpringBootPlugin.BOM_COORDINATES))
    kapt(platform(SpringBootPlugin.BOM_COORDINATES))
  }
}
```

In a subproject (the library in question):

```
dependencies {
  kapt("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")
}
tasks {
  compileJava {
    dependsOn(processResources)
  }
  compileKotlin {
    dependsOn(processResources)
  }
}
```

`application.yml` file is present in `rootProject/subproject/src/main/resources` and configuration properties are defined there.

IntelliJ shows this hint:

> Spring Boot Configuration Annotation Processor not found in classpath.

And no links (no ctrl+clicking, no docs) exist between configuration in `application.yml` and the code.

I have this in the main @Configuration class of the library:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SecurityConfigurationParameters::class)
class WebSecurityConfig(...) { ... }
```

and this is the properties class:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "security")
class SecurityConfigurationParameters(
    @DefaultValue("false")
    val csrfEnabled: Boolean,
    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    val token: TokenConfig
)
```

And this something like this in `application.yml`:

```
security:
  csrf-enabled: true
  token.private-secret: ...
```

This same setup works in a standalone app.

So far I had a suspicion that the problem is that this is a library, but adding main class with main function and `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class didn't help.
My last suspicion is that the problem is somewhere in gradle or intellij.

---

Edit: I've narrowed it down to IntelliJ. I see that kapt has generated metadata json in `build/tmp/kapt3/classes/main/META-INF`

Comment: I can point you to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/17560, it seems related. But I have never used `kapt` myself

Comment: @ThanksForAllTheFish that seems to be a different problem to mine, also as I've stated above this setup actually works as intended in my standalone application gradle project, but breaks down in my `parent/subproject` gradle project.

Comment: Make the problem known [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues). With a reproducible test case.

Comment: Yes, I'm planning to.